# Frechet differentiability of ODE functional

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functional-calculus, frechet-derivative

---

### **Setup:**

Suppose that $q(x)$ is a strictly positive $C^{2}$ function and consider the initial value problem:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
y''+q(x)y=&0\\
y(0)=&k\\
y'(0)=&c
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
We know that such an initial value problem has a unique solution which we will denote by $f^q(x)$.

Define the functional $F_{x}$ by

### \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
F_{x}:C^{2}(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})&\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
%C^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^2;\mathbb{R})\\
F_{x}(q)&\mapsto f^{q}(x).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

### **Question:**

Is the functional $F_{x}$ Frechet differentiable?  How can we determine if it is?

Comment: I guess if you play with the integral of Picard's theorem you will get differentiability

Comment: By the way, you need also initial conditions on the first derivative also.

Comment: @tst what do you mean by the integral in Picard's theorem?  Also, I added the ic for the first derivative.

Comment: What's the topology you're putting on $C^{2}(\mathbb{R} ; \mathbb{R})$?

Comment: The uniform topology

Comment: Do you know the Picard–Lindelöf theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $q_{0}\in C^{2}$. To find the Gateaux derivative let $p\in C^{2}$ and
consider $q_{0}+tp$ where $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Consider
\begin{gather*}
y^{\prime\prime}+(q_{0}(x)+tp(x))y(x)=0,\\
y(0)=k,\quad y^{\prime}(0)=c.
\end{gather*}
The $y$ depends on $x$, $t$, $q_{0}$, $p$, so we can write it as
$y=y(x,t;q_{0},p)$. In turn, we have
\begin{gather*}
\frac{\partial^{2}y}{\partial x^{2}}(x,t;q_{0},p)+(q_{0}(x)+tp(x))y(x,t;q_{0}%
,p)=0,\\
y(0,t;q_{0},p)=k,\quad\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}(0,t;q_{0},p)(0)=c.
\end{gather*}
Formally, if we take the derivative with respect to $t$ at $t=0$ we get
\begin{gather*}
\frac{\partial^{3}y}{\partial x^{2}\partial t}(x,0;q_{0},p)+(q_{0}%
(x)+0p(x))\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}(x,0;q_{0},p)+1p(x)y(x,0;q_{0},p)=0,\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}(0,0;q_{0},p)=0,\quad\frac{\partial^{2}%
y}{\partial x\partial t}(0,0;q_{0},p)=0.
\end{gather*}
So if we write $y_{q_{0}}(x):=y(x,0;q_{0},p)$ and $z_{p}(x):=\frac{\partial
y}{\partial t}(x,0;q_{0},p)$, we have that $z$ solves the differential
equation
\begin{gather*}
z_{p}^{\prime\prime}+q_{0}z_{p}+py_{q_{0}}=0,\\
z_{p}(0)=0,\quad z_{p}^{\prime}(0)=0.
\end{gather*}
This can actually made rigorous.

So if we consider $F_{x}:C^{2}\rightarrow C$ and fix $q_{0}$ and a direction
$p$, the conjecture is that the directional derivative $\frac{\partial F_{x}%
}{\partial p}(q_{0})=z_{p}(x)$. If this is the case, then the Frechet
derivative at $q_{0}$ is given by $dF_{x}(q_{0})(p)=\frac{\partial F_{x}%
}{\partial p}(q_{0})=z_{p}(x)$ and so we need to prove that$$
\lim_{q\rightarrow q_{0}}\frac{F_{x}(q)-F_{x}(q_{0})-dF_{x}(q_{0})(q-q_{0}%
)}{\Vert q-q_{0}\Vert_{C^{2}}}=0.
$$
Let $y_{q}$ be the solution of the differential equation
\begin{gather*}
y_{q}^{\prime\prime}+q(x)y_{q}(x)=0,\\
y_{q}(0)=k,\quad y_{q}^{\prime}(0)=c.
\end{gather*}
Then we can rewrite the limit as$$
\lim_{q\rightarrow q_{0}}\frac{y_{q}(x)-y_{q_{0}}(x)-z_{q-q_{0}}(x)}{\Vert
q-q_{0}\Vert_{C^{2}}}=0,
$$
where $z_{q-q_{0}}$ solves
\begin{gather*}
z_{q-q_{0}}^{\prime\prime}+q_{0}z_{q-q_{0}}+(q-q_{0})y_{q_{0}}=0,\\
z_{q-q_{0}}(0)=0,\quad z_{q-q_{0}}^{\prime}(0)=0.
\end{gather*}
Since $y_{q}^{\prime\prime}+qy_{q}=0$, $y_{q_{0}}^{\prime\prime}+q_{0}%
y_{q_{0}}=0$, and $z_{q-q_{0}}^{\prime\prime}+q_{0}z_{q-q_{0}}+(q-q_{0}%
)y_{q_{0}}=0$, by subtracting the differential equations we get
\begin{align*}
y_{q}^{\prime\prime}-y_{q_{0}}^{\prime\prime}-z_{q-q_{0}}^{\prime\prime}  &
=-qy_{q}+q_{0}y_{q_{0}}+q_{0}z_{q-q_{0}}+(q-q_{0})y_{q_{0}}\\
& =-q(y_{q}-y_{q_{0}}-z_{q-q_{0}})+(q_{0}-q)z_{q-q_{0}}%
\end{align*}
with $(y_{q}-y_{q_{0}}-z_{q-q_{0}})(0)=0$ and $(y_{q}-y_{q_{0}}-z_{q-q_{0}%
})^{\prime}(0)=0$. By integration$$
(y_{q}-y_{q_{0}}-z_{q-q_{0}})(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{s}-q(t)(y_{q}-y_{q_{0}%
}-z_{q-q_{0}})(t)+(q_{0}-q)(t)z_{q-q_{0}}(t)\,dtds
$$
and so$$
|(y_{q}-y_{q_{0}}-z_{q-q_{0}})(x)|\leq\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{s}|q(t)||(y_{q}%
-y_{q_{0}}-z_{q-q_{0}})(t)|+|(q_{0}-q)(t)z_{q-q_{0}}(t)|\,dtds.
$$
It follows by Gronwall's inequality that%
\begin{align*}
|(y_{q}-y_{q_{0}}-z_{q-q_{0}})(x)|  & \leq\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{s}%
|(q_{0}-q)(t)z_{q-q_{0}}(t)|\,dtds\exp\left(  \int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}%
^{s}|q(t)||(y_{q}-y_{q_{0}}-z_{q-q_{0}})(t)|\,dtds\right)  \\
& \leq\Vert q-q_{0}\Vert_{C^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{s}|z_{q-q_{0}%
}(t)|\,dtds\exp\left(  \int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{s}|q(t)||(y_{q}-y_{q_{0}%
}-z_{q-q_{0}})(t)|\,dtds\right)
\end{align*}
and so$$
\frac{|(y_{q}-y_{q_{0}}-z_{q-q_{0}})(x)|}{\Vert q-q_{0}\Vert_{C^{2}}}\leq
\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{s}|z_{q-q_{0}}(t)|\,dtds\exp\left(  \int_{0}^{x}\int%
_{0}^{s}|q(t)||(y_{q}-y_{q_{0}}-z_{q-q_{0}})(t)|\,dtds\right)  .
$$
It remains to prove that the right hand-side goes to zero as $q\rightarrow
q_{0}$. By integration$$
z_{q-q_{0}}(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{s}-q_{0}(t)z_{q-q_{0}}(t)+(q_{0}%
-q)(t)y_{q_{0}}(t)\,dtds
$$
and so by Gronwall's inequality
\begin{align*}
|z_{q-q_{0}}(x)|  & \leq\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{s}|(q_{0}-q)(t)y_{q_{0}%
}(t)|\,dtds\exp\left(  \int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{s}|q_{0}(t)||\,dtds\right)  \\
& \leq\Vert q-q_{0}\Vert_{C^{2}}L.
\end{align*}
Hence, $\Vert z_{q-q_{0}}\Vert_{\infty}\leq\Vert q-q_{0}\Vert_{C^{2}%
}L\rightarrow0$ as $q\rightarrow q_{0}$. I am skipping the proof that $y_{q}$
is bounded.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to include the proof of boundedness and the rigerous part of the first section (I'll award some reward points for it)

Comment: You just have to use Gronwal's inequality the same way I did. Why don't you try and if you get stuck, I'll help?

Comment: You don't need the rigorous part at the beginning. It was just needed to guess the form of the differential. So only the second part of the proof, starting from "So if we consider $F_x$" is what you really need. I was just trying to explain how I "guessed" the Frechet differential.